# TypeError: 'abc' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, lambda, highcharts, django-views

I am trying to display a chart in my django app using this link [Integrate graphs in Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/04/03/how-to-integrate-highcharts-js-with-django.html)

Here is my Views.py

```
def json_example(request):
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/json_example.html')

def chart_data(request):
    dataset = DispatchPlan.objects.all()
    print("dataset is ", dataset)

    # port_display_name = dict()
    # for port_tuple in Passenger.PORT_CHOICES:
    #     port_display_name[port_tuple[0]] = port_tuple[1]

    chart = {
        'chart': {'type': 'pie'},
        'title': {'text': 'Titanic Survivors by Ticket Class'},
        'series': [{
            'name': 'Embarkation Port',
            'data': list(map(lambda row: {'name': row['weight'], 'y': row['route_distance']}, dataset))
        }]
    }

    return JsonResponse(chart)
```

When I run the app it shows the following error:

> TypeError: 'DispatchPlan' object is not subscriptable

in this line

```
'data': list(map(lambda row: {'name': row['weight'], 'y': row['route_distance']}, dataset))
```

I am guessing its because I am not mapping it correctly, How do I solve this ?

Traceback:

Traceback:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\Downloads-HDD\aggregator-master\django_school\classroom\views\teachers.py"
>   in chart_data
>     884.             'data': [{'name': row.weight, 'y': row.route_distance} for row in dataset]
>
> File
>   "D:\Downloads-HDD\aggregator-master\django_school\classroom\views\teachers.py"
>   in 
>     884.             'data': [{'name': row.weight, 'y': row.route_distance} for row in dataset]
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /shipper/json-example/data/
>   Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'weight'

Models.py

```
class DispatchPlan(models.Model):
    bid_status_choices = (
        ('Hold', 'Hold'), ('Active', 'Active'), ('Assigned', 'Assigned'), ('Dispatched', 'Dispatched'),
        ('Delayed', 'Delayed'), ('Delivered', 'Delivered'))
    mtypes = (('Fragile', 'Fragile'), ('Non-Fragile', 'Non-Fragile'))

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispatch_quizzes')
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    truck_type = models.ForeignKey(truck_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispatch_type')
    truck_name = models.ForeignKey(truck_name, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispatch_name')
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    total_trucks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    material_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0, choices=mtypes)
    scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255, default=0)
    offered_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Active', choices=bid_status_choices)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    route_distance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    route_tat = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    etd = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    eta = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    route_link = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Model instances are not dictionaries, they are objects with attributes. You need to use dot notation:

```
'data': list(map(lambda row: {'name': row.weight, 'y': row.route_distance}, dataset))
```

Note also, this code is not particularly Pythonic. It's more idiomatic to use a list comprehension:

```
'data': [{'name': row.weight, 'y': row.route_distance} for row in dataset]
```

Comment: It is giving me `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'weight'` but I have weight in my DispatchPlan

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: added trace back in question

Comment: But that's not possible with the code you have shown. Either dataset *is* a list of dicts, in which case your original code would have worked, or it is a list of instances, in which case my code would work.

Comment: I can see what it is. Perhaps you should show the full traceback from the original code.